# Encryption - Decryption with AES/BlowFish/DESede and Enum

Tags: java, encryption, enums, secret-key

First of all I wanna say thank you...

I wrote a program which one is doing encryption and decryption with Enum.
Enum has AES,BlowFish,DESede. My program will support these 3 encryption algorithm.

Then I wanted to Generate a SecretKey with SecretKeyFactory.But I think,I made a mistake to generate a key. (Obviously I loose myself in code.I have no idea about what can I do...)

My Code is below. **This program's purpose is**;

- Users will write encryption and decryption method parameters. (Text,Encryption Algorithm)
- Algorithm type will choose in Enum type. (Enum has 3 algorithm format)
- According to the entered Encryption Type,program will encrypt entered text.

**I know my code is really terrible**. It has lots of unnecessary declaration and logical mistakes.

Code is working fine sometimes,sometimes will crash.

**EDIT =** Question is my code doesnt work always. Sometimes gives error. **Error is =** *javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded*

*Thank you for answering*.

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class SymetricAlgorithms {

    private static enum algorithms { //Enum declaration 3 encryption types here

        AES, BlowFish, DESede;

    }

    private static String data = "HOWCANISOLVETHIS"; //this will be encrypt and decrypt

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

        SecretKey kgen = GenerateKey(); // Create a key.
        String encrypText = encrypt(kgen, data, algorithms.AES); //encrypt method calling here.
        String decrypText = dencypt(kgen, encrypText, algorithms.AES);//decrypt method calling here.
        System.out.println("plaintext = " + data + " key = " + kgen
                + "\nEncryptedText = " + encrypText
                + "\nDecryptedText = " + decrypText);

    }

    public static String dencypt(SecretKey inKey, String text, algorithms eValue)throws Throwable {//decryption
        try {
            byte[] text2 = text.getBytes(); //convert from parameters TEXT to Bytes
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES"); //Cipher initialize and choose encryption method (AES)
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, inKey); //cipher process
            byte plainTextByte[] = new byte[20]; //Creating byte array
            plainTextByte =cipher.doFinal(text2);//using byte array to assign ciphers result
            System.out.println(plainTextByte);
            return new String(plainTextByte);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Data Cant Decrypted !");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;


    }

    public static String encrypt(SecretKey inKey, String text, algorithms eValue)
            throws Throwable {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = null; //cipher declaration
            switch (eValue) {//Enum. 3 types here and control structure for Users choosing encryption type is acceptable
            case AES:cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
                break;
            case BlowFish:Cipher cipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("BlowFish");
            cipher = cipher2;
                break;
            case DESede:Cipher cipher3 = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
            cipher=cipher3;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Unexpectable value input.");
                break;

            }
            System.out.println(inKey);
            //Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, inKey);
            byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));//cipher result is assign to byte array
            System.out.println(ciphertext);
            return new String(ciphertext);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Unexpectable algorithm type !");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

    public static SecretKey GenerateKey() throws Throwable {//Generate a key for using crypt
            //could sb explain these? =D I loose myself. I combined codes from finding internet...Failed...    
        try {
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
            SecureRandom prng = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            byte bytes[] = new byte[20];
            prng.nextBytes(bytes);
            String passwordTemp = prng.toString();
            String saltTemp = passwordTemp;
            char[] password = passwordTemp.toCharArray();
            byte[] salt = saltTemp.getBytes();
            KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 65536, 128);
            SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
            SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
            return secret;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Key cant be generated !");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I think you should express your question... better. What exactly is the question? And exactly is the problem with the key generation and how does it show up?

Comment: Question is my code doesnt work always. Sometimes gives error.
Error is = javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded

Run the program 10-20times. Sometimes gives error... U will show if u will run it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The theme of the problem is misunderstanding of the relationship between Strings and bytes.  At the end of the encrypt method, what do you think these two lines do:

```
byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(...
return new String(ciphertext);
```

The last line takes the encrypted bytes, which could be almost anything, and **attempts** to interpret those bytes as encoding some characters of a string. Using what encoding? String constructor with no character encoding argument uses system default encoding, which depends on JVM/OS/Locale.  Lets say it is UTF-8. Are you guaranteed that there will actually **be** some character for the encrypted bytes?  Answer: NO.   Will you get the same bytes back, when you take the resulting string and call .getBytes("UTF-8").  Answer: No, there are mutliple byte sequences encoding the same characters, thus new String(bytes, "UTF-8").getBytes("UTF-8") is not guaranteed to return the bytes you started with.

In summary, don't attempt to interpret arbitrary bytes as a string.  Make your encrypt method return byte[], and your decryp method take an array of bytes to decode-- then it will work.

It is not necessary to make your program work, but if you must represent the encrypted bytes as a string, consider base64 encoding, or hexadecimal encoding -- these encodings uniquely map every possible byte (or sequence of bytes) to a string.

**UPDATE**: here is a more concise generateKey() method.  It allows you to pass the password in as an argument.

```
public static SecretKey generateKey(String password) {
    try {
        SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        byte saltBytes[] = new byte[20];
        secureRandom.nextBytes(saltBytes);

        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), saltBytes, 65536, 128);
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);

        return new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Key cant be generated !");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Keith. I will examine your advice this night. And I will send reanswer to you.

Comment: You are right Keith. **I did nonsensical things for convertion String to Byte and Byte to String.** I fixed problems.
**Lastly**, my code's GenerateKey method could be better then now? I used lots of lines for only generate one key.Any tips?
(_Sorry my bad English..._)